# Plotting time-series data using matplotlib 3.13 and month JAN not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I used matplolib 3.13 and run the codes in [Plotting time-series data using matplotlib and showing year only at start of year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49725631/plotting-time-series-data-using-matplotlib-and-showing-year-only-at-start-of-yea)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates
from datetime import datetime

t = [datetime(2016,1,1), datetime(2017,12,31)]
x = [0,1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t,x)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator((1,4,7,10)))

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("\n%Y"))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%b"))
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0, ha="center")

plt.show()
```

The graph does not show Jan :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhPYV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the major_formatter to:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%b\n%Y"))
```

Now it will display both the year and the month on each major tick.

Hope this helps!